# find -print0 with 2 files only shows 1

Tags: bash, find, gnu-parallel

As an example, I have two files in my directory:`video.mp4` and `video.webm`
If I use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.webm"
```

I got correctly:

```
/video.webm
./video.mp4
```

But if I add `-print0`, that I need to pipe to `parallel` I got:

```
./video.webm
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `print0` attempt looks like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.webm" -print0
```

The `-print0` is processed with the 2nd `-iname` option, in effect:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.mp4" -o ( -iname "*.webm"  -print0)
```

One option would be to add explicit parens to insure the `-print0` is applied against both `-iname` options, eg:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.webm" \) -print0
```

Comment: I was trying that but wrong thanks!